# iOS tab bar issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app i'v `UITabbarController` as rootviewController with 3 tabs on it, each tab has its own `UINavigationController`.On the first tab i'v attached a `UIViewController` that hides tab bar and navigation bar, by click on a button user can go to next screen that will show tab bar as well as navigation bar.Now the problem is when i click on first tab on this view controller (which is already selected by default) it takes me on previous view controller and i want it should stay on the same screen.How to achieve this?

**Edit**: I dont want to disable bar item at index 0 as this turns it into `UIControlStateDisabled` which make it different looks from others.

**Is there any way to set image for `UIControlStateDisabled` for tab bar item?**
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: disable user-interface on next screen of first tabbaaritem.

Comment: Thanks Joge but tab bar does not have 'setUserInterfaceEnabled' method and if i use 'setEnabled' method then it turn tab bar item into disabled state(look and feel change from other items)

Comment: How did you attached UIViewController and hide it? Would you add the  code?

Comment: push/pop view controller to navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be helpfull...

```
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:1]setEnabled:FALSE];
```

set "objectAtIndex" that you want..

Comment: i tried this but it turn that tab bar item into disabled state(UIControlsate) which make it different look from other item